# Can i add two new columns to all my tables through a MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

In my database i have like 200 tables which starts from pre_table_XX( example : pre_table_1, pre_table_2, pre_table_3, pre_table_4 etc  ). currently i need to add two new coloumns two all these tables by using a mysql query at once. below is an example of one of my tables

example table

```
trackID MyID    Rid     panelID timestamp           useragent_browser   useragent_OS
1       17      123     25      2014-04-29 10:02:01 Default Browser     unknown NULL
2       17      123     25      2014-04-30 05:11:01 Default Browser     unknown NULL
3       17      123     25      2014-05-15 06:44:02 Default Browser     unknown NULL
4       17      59595   25      2014-10-06 07:50:30 Default Browser     unknown 0
```

I need to add two new columns to each of these tables known as, device_name and browser

i tried it like this for no avail

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'abc_db' AND table_name LIKE 'pre_table_%'

ALTER TABLE `abc_db`.`stats` 

ADD COLUMN `device_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL AFTER `useragent_os`,

ADD COLUMN `browser` VARCHAR(45) NULL AFTER `device_name`;
```

can anybody help on this. putting a mysql loop kind of thing would do i guess!!!

Comment: It would be easy you can do using any language e.g. java/php